# target platform for c++ VS2015 to XP don't work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a project in c++ vs2015 that I want to run it on Windows XP,

for that In property page I set toolset to `v140_xp`

but still when I try to run it on Windows XP I get error that my app not valid for win32

exist other configuration or installation that I must to do?

Comment: Double-check with Dumpbin.exe /headers.  The "machine" and the "subsystem version" matter.  Standard mistakes are targeting x64 and forgetting to change the toolset setting as well for the Release build.

Comment: why you don't write this as a answer?

Comment: I don't know what the answer is, you did not provide enough details.  Just write it yourself once you figured it out.

Comment: thanks you help to me so much problem was in "subsystem version"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

out of  `toolset` propery that set to `v140_xp` in property general

also set in linker->system->`subsystem`